# The XServer config file is not found

Tags: 14.04, xorg, xserver

I have recently purchased a new discrete GPU and have to configure the XServer. In a forum I found the advise first to back-up the config-file like that: `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak` 
but it just puts out the error:  **file or directory not found**

So if I cannot back-up the file how should I open and configure it? Please help!

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit, with an AMD Kaveri-APU with 16GB RAM. The GPU I want to get to work in my system is the AMD R9-280.

Comment: [Simple run # echo $DISPLAY , to detect which it , then run  # Xorg -configure :0 , # sudo cp ~/home/.xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf]

Answer (score 0):

**xorg.conf** is not found by default .

you can boot into recovery mode and select Root Shell.

run :

```
  X -configure
```

Then:

```
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reboot and you can edit the new **Xorg.conf.**

Comment: Okay, I could access the root shell fine but when I typed in `X -configure` this error appeared: **Fatal server error: could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock   Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help**

Comment: Ok so that issue is dealt with. So now how can I open it? I tried `gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` but then my system got all laggy and I had to shut it down. What did I do wrong?

Comment: [check /var/log/Xorg.0.log Fatal server error: could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock may because conflict files in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d]

Comment: Did exactly like this and now my screen looks post apocalyptic :(